# Embedded time series database?

Tags: sqlite, time-series

My group uses SQLite for our commercial application and we're super happy with it. Lightweight and "embedded" into our application.

However, we're starting to work with time series data and we don't want to ham-fist time-series data into SQLITE.

Two questions:

Are we thinking about this the right way?

Is there a time-series database that's meant to be lightweight and embedded the way SQLite is?

Our data would probably be 10 curves once per second 24/7.

New databases would be made on average every month.

Answer (score 1):

Try [InfluxDB](https://www.influxdata.com/) which is purpose built for time series data.

There is also an extension that will let you embed it in a java app if that is what you are using.

https://github.com/APISENSE/embed-influxDB

If not maybe you can try reverse engineering that library to see how to embed it using your stack.